# Newly swapped debian laptop has working battery, but loses power when unplugged from ac adapter

Tags: debian, thinkpad, battery

I recently installed Debian Bullseye on my Thinkpad T430, and everything works great except for the battery. When the AC adapter is unplugged, the computer loses power. the battery works fine when put in a T430 running windows. Is my battery shot? is it a software issue?

Output of Upower

```
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               SANYO
  model:                45N1001
  serial:               267
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sun 04 Aug 2019 10:05:21 PM EDT (49 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              5.43 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         26.46 Wh
    energy-full-design:  56.16 Wh
    energy-rate:         10.98 W
    voltage:             11.858 V
    time to full:        1.9 hours
    percentage:          20%
    capacity:            47.1154%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-low-charging-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1564970718  20.000  charging
  History (rate):
    1564970721  10.980  charging
    1564970718  10.979  charging
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _Ethan Cope_, a battery with only 47% of new capacity is an old and failing battery, and only 20% full is not a good condition to test in. After you charge it up to its 47% ceiling, does this occur after you have installed tlp ? https://www.tecmint.com/tlp-increase-and-optimize-linux-battery-life/ https://www.2daygeek.com/tlp-increase-optimize-linux-laptop-battery-life/  https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/blob/master/README.md Please click [edit] after you've tried it and advise. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].